# How to pass data from a custom view to a controller in iOS?

Tags: ios

I have a custom subview that is shared between controllers/views. I want to "bubble up" some data/event to the controller when the user takes an action in the custom view (i.e. tap a button, select an option). What is the correct way to do this in iOS? Note that I am not using Xcode nor Interface Builder. I would like to know how to do this in code.

Comment: If the user can interact with the view, shouldn't it be a UIControl instead? If it is a control the standard way would be Target-Action.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you create a model to hold your data and you either create a [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html) for your custom subview or use [blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)/[closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) (the first approach is usually preferred). When the action occurs you "bubble up" the data in a model instance and call a delegate method or block depending on what you choose, with the model instance as a parameter. Usually the delegate is the view controller but you could also add some indirection if necessary to sparse things out (have a separate object handling the actions of your custom view).